# Nested IF formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel 2013 spreadsheet in which I'm trying to nest 2 formulas into one cell.

I have the 1st formula this being =IF(B2+15>N2,X,Y) where B2 & N2 are dates.

I need to add another formula where N2 is blank, something along the lines of 
=IF(B2

Can you please recommend a solution?

Comment: Try `isblank()` function to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(N2),Today(),IF(B2+15>N2,X,Y))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives 'N2 is blank' in the cell

Comment: @Jimmy... Change that bit to whatever you what to show when N2 is blank

Comment: Thanks CallumDA. How do i get it to show today's date so that it updates daily. Similar to "=TODAY())

Comment: Thanks CallumDA, that's a great help.